# What is the probability that if a randomly chosen product is defective, then it came from machine X?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Two machines, A and B, each independently produces a product. Machine X makes 70 percent of the product while Y makes 30 percent. From past statistics, 5 percent made by X and 6 percent made by Y are defective. Given that a product randomly chosen was defective, what is the probability it came from X?

How could I start with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You could start by reading about [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Comment: @barakmanos this is not very useful isn't it?

Comment: Oh, it actually very much is. It is exactly where you need to start if you want to solve this problem on your own...

Answer (score 1):

Hint to get started:

Let $10000$ products be produced.

Find out how many of these products are expected to be defective and find out how many of the defective products are expected to come from $X$.

Comment: This is my answer X=7000, Y= 3000 Defective X = 350 and Y = 180. Any hints how to continue from here?

Comment: So there are $530$ defectives in total and $350$ of them come from machine $X$. If I pick a defective one then what is the chance that it comes from machine $X$?

Comment: defective units from X/Total defective units. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
$$P=\frac{\text{defective units from X}}{\text{total defective units}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider an event:

$$
D = \text{"a randomly selected product is deffetive"}.
$$

Obviously, the probability of $D$ is conditional on $X$ and $Y$, i.e., you have to consider probabilities $P(D|X)$ and $P(D|Y)$ as well as probabilities $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$. You have all the information needed to calculate these probabilities:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X) &= \\
P(D|X) &= \\
P(Y) &= \\
P(D|Y) &= 
\end{aligned}
$$

The question you have to answer is: *what is the probability $P(X|D)$?*

To answer that question you have to apply a Bayes' theorem:

$$
P(X|D) = \frac{P(X)P(D|X)}{P(X)P(D|X) + P(Y)P(D|Y)}.
$$